# How to format the input of Shiny updated numericInput but not change the actual value?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, format, numeric-input

In the following example, the `numberInput` "Number C" is calculated and updated as "Number A" divided "Number B". When the result is an infinite decimal, this leads to a number with lots of digits to "Number C". I would like to round the infinite decimal to the second or third the digits, making the appearance easier to read for "Number C". In the same time, however, I don't want to apply the `round` function to `num_C` because in the real world I want to apply "Number C" for other calculation and I want to use the number as is. In other words, I want to find a way to format the number's appearance but not the acutal value, like format a cell in an Excel spreadsheet to show only limited digits but not change the acutal value. Is this possible to do in Shiny?

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(inputId = "A", "Number A", value = 2),
  numericInput(inputId = "B", "Number B", value = 3),
  numericInput(inputId = "C", "Number C [A/B]", value = 1)
)

# Server logic
server <- function(input, output, session){

  observe({
    req(input$A, input$B)
    num_C <- input$A/input$B
    updateNumericInput(
      inputId = "C",
      session = session,
      value = num_C
    )
  })
}

# Complete app with UI and server components
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I would suggest filing a GH issue to Rstudio's shiny repo to ask for a format argument to `numericInput()` and `updateNumericInput()`.

Comment: @Phil Thanks for your comment. This is something we can do, but I would like to wait for a while making sure I did not miss any solutions.

Comment: @Phil : with my (limited) understanding of the underlying *input type=„number“*, I don’t think this is really possible because input$C corresponds to the *value* and that’s all this widget really has, ie there is no *format* property and if one would use eg *pattern* to restrict to two decimals, then the *value* and *input$C* will be affected likewise and you don’t have the full precision value anymore. I think you have to store it separately, see eg Maurits‘ answer.

Comment: @RolandASc this is why I believe it should be a feature request to the Shiny team at RStudio

Answer (score 5):

You could use a `reactive` expression for `num_C`

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(inputId = "A", "Number A", value = 2),
  numericInput(inputId = "B", "Number B", value = 3),
  numericInput(inputId = "C", "Number C [A/B]", value = 1)
)

# Server logic
server <- function(input, output, session){

  num_C <- reactive({
      req(input$A, input$B)
      input$A / input$B
  })

  observe(
      updateNumericInput(
          inputId = "C",
          session = session,
          value = format(num_C(), digits = 2))
      )

}

# Complete app with UI and server components
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

`num_C()` will then return the "un-rounded" value, whereas we use the rounded value `format(num_C(), digits = 2)` in `updateNumericInput`.

---

### A partial update

For what it's worth, here's an incomplete update

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(inputId = "A", "Number A", value = 2),
  numericInput(inputId = "B", "Number B", value = 3),
  numericInput(inputId = "C", "Number C [A/B]", value = 1),
  textOutput("value"),
  textOutput("rounded_value")
)

# Server logic
server <- function(input, output, session){

  num_C <- reactiveValues(
      value = NULL,
      rounded_value = NULL
  )

  observeEvent(input$A | input$B, {
      num_C$value <- input$A / input$B
      num_C$rounded_value <- round(num_C$value, 1)
  })

  observeEvent(input$C, {
      num_C$value <- input$C
      num_C$rounded_value <- input$C
  })

  output$value <- renderText(
      sprintf("Number C = %f", num_C$value)
  )
  output$rounded_value <- renderText(
      sprintf("Number C (rounded) = %f", num_C$rounded_value)
  )

}

# Complete app with UI and server components
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The idea is to use `reactiveValues` to track the full precision and rounded value of number C. This works in as far as

1. changing numbers A, B through `numericInput` will correctly calculate (and display) the full precision and rounded numbers for C in the `textOutput`s.
2. changing number C  through `numericInput` will also correctly display the full precision number (which is equal to the rounded) in the `textOutput`s.

*However*, I've been unsuccessful with using `updateNumericInput` to update the value for C with the rounded number when numbers A and B were changed.

To be continued...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have upvoted your post. However, now `input$C` would be a rounded value, which is what I want in the appearance, but not for the subsequent calculation. For example, later I will do `input$C * 100000`. I want to calculate this value using `0.666666667`, but showing the appearance as `0.67`.

Comment: @www The idea was to use `num_C()` instead of `input$C`. The former will have the full precision value. Wouldn’t that work?

Comment: This is a good idea. But in this case, I want to give the users the flexibility that when they change the input value to "Number C", for example, `0.25`, the subsequent calculation will use `input$C` (`0.25`), not `num_c()` (`0.67`).

Comment: @www Hmm, so just to clarify: You'd like to change the input of "C" either (1) indirectly through changing "A" and/or "B", in which case "C = A/B" should be rounded, or (2) directly through changing "C" itself, in which case there should be no rounding. Is that correct? I think that case is trickier to realise. I'll have to think about this.

Comment: Let's say what `C = A/B` or the number directly put into `C` is a decimal numbers, such as `0.6666667`. I want to round it to `0.67` in its appearance, but behind the scene it is still `0.6666667`. What I am asking may not be possible, but in an Excel spreadsheet, it is common to format the cell number with rounding, but not change the actual cell values. I would like to have the same behavior as my numericInput `C`.

Comment: @www Ok, I think I understand. But the additional difficulty here is that you want to have two options for changing "C": Either directly or indirectly through changing "A" and/or "B". Having a number rounded only for display is possible for either separate scenario, but I'm not sure (yet) how to link them.

Comment: Thanks. I know what I am asking may not be possible. But since it is common in Excel, I want to post my question here to see if anyone has any idea. It is OK if the answer is not possible.

Comment: @www I completely agree with you, it sounds like a sensible feature/request. I haven't given up on this;-) I will take another look at this tomorrow morning (it's getting late here in Australia).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will also keep looking into this.

Answer (score 3):

Simpliest thing to do would be to count how long `input$C` is and apply a rounding figure - while saving the true value as a dummy variable:

```
library(shiny)
#this counts the decimal places of a value
decimalplaces <- function(x) {
  if ((x %% 1) != 0) {
    nchar(strsplit(sub('0+$', '', as.character(x)), ".", fixed=TRUE)[[1]][[2]])
  } else {
    return(0)
  }
}

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(inputId = "A", "Number A", value = 2),
  numericInput(inputId = "B", "Number B", value = 3),
  numericInput(inputId = "C", "Number C [A/B]", value = 1)
)

# Server logic
server <- function(input, output, session){
  num_C <- reactiveValues(
    value = NULL
  )

  observeEvent(input$A|input$B,{

    num_C$value <- input$A/input$B
    updateNumericInput(
      inputId = "C",
      session = session,
      value = round(num_C$value,2)
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$C, {
    #identify if num_C is greater than 2 dc
  if(decimalplaces(input$C)>2){
    num_C$value <- input$C
  }
    updateNumericInput(
      inputId = "C",
      session = session,
      value = round(num_C$value,2)
    )

  })
  #check that everything is working correctly. 
  observeEvent( input$A|input$B|input$C,{
    print(paste0(num_C$value," ", input$C))
  })
}

# Complete app with UI and server components
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

thanks to @Maurits Evers for the majority of the code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have upvoted it and will check later.

Answer (score 2):

I just changed the code of Maurits a little bit by adding a `flag` and an `observeEvent` for the `value <- reactiveValue()` that holds the actual value. Now, "C" will always show the rounded value, but `value` will store the actual.

I hope this is useful...

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(inputId = "A", "Number A", value = 2),
  numericInput(inputId = "B", "Number B", value = 2),
  numericInput(inputId = "C", "Number C [A/B]", value = 1),
  textOutput("value"),
  textOutput("rounded_value")
)

# Server logic
server <- function(input, output, session){

  value <- reactiveVal(1)
  rounded_value <- reactiveVal()
  flag <- reactiveVal(T)

  observeEvent(input$A | input$B, {
    value(input$A / input$B)
    rounded_value(round(value(), 2))
  })


  observeEvent(input$C, {
    if(flag()){
      value(input$C)
      rounded_value(round(input$C, 2))
    }else{
      flag(T)
    }
  })

  observeEvent(value(),{
    flag(F)
    updateNumericInput(session, "C", value = rounded_value())
  })



  output$value <- renderText(
    sprintf("Number C = %f", value())
  )
  output$rounded_value <- renderText(
    sprintf("Number C (rounded) = %f", rounded_value())
  )

}

# Complete app with UI and server components
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have given you an upvote first. I am busy today, but I will review your answer and let you know if it works when I have time.